# React - Get Components to use data in props rather than new API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application which makes a couple of API requests in a couple of components.  I'm trying to modify my code so that rather than these components making new requests on `componentDidMount()` instead they use  data that has been made available in `props`.  I have this working for one component but not the other - as far as I can see there's no difference in who I'm handling these components so I think my method must be at fault.

The function which makes the API call is in `app.js` below.  The result of the call is saved to state (`wantedCards` or `ownedCards` depending on the API call) and then passed to the component as a `prop` in React Router (`BrowserRouter`)

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    ownedCards: "",
    wantedCards: "",
    data: "null",
    loading: false,
    error: false,
  };

  loadCardData = (props) => {
 
    let path = props.path.split("/");
    console.log("NEW PATH2 IS " + path[2]);

    if (path[2] == "own" && props.ownedCards.length < 1) {
      console.log("OWN TRUE");
      var url = `https://apicall/getOwnedCards?user=${path[1]}`;
      return axios
        .get(`${url}`)
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            data: result.data,
            ownedCards: result.data,
            loading: false,
            error: false,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("error: ", error);
          this.setState({
            error: `${error}`,
            loading: false,
          });
        });
    } else if (path[2] == "want" && props.wantedCards.length < 1) {
      console.log("WANT TRUE");
      var url = `https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/cards-fvyrn/service/Cards/incoming_webhook/getWantedCards?user=${path[1]}`;
      return axios
        .get(`${url}`)
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            data: result.data,
            wantedCards: result.data,
            loading: false,
            error: false,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("error: ", error);
          this.setState({
            error: `${error}`,
            loading: false,
          });
        });
    } else {
      return;
    }

render(props) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter path="foo">
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/:username"
              render={(props) => (
                <Redirect to={`/${props.match.params.username}/own`} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/:username/own"
              render={(props) => (
                <NewTable
                  status="Own"
                  p1={props.location.pathname.split("/")[1]}
                  p2={props.location.pathname.split("/")[2]}
                  p3={props.location.pathname.split("/")[3]}
                  p4={props.location.pathname.split("/")[4]}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  ownedCards={this.state.ownedCards}
                  loadCardData={this.loadCardData}
                  path={props.location.pathname}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/:username/own/team/:id"
              render={(props) => (
                <CardColumns
                  p1={props.location.pathname.split("/")[1]}
                  p2={props.location.pathname.split("/")[2]}
                  p3={props.location.pathname.split("/")[3]}
                  p4={props.location.pathname.split("/")[4]}
                  status="Own"
                  ownedCards={this.state.ownedCards}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  loadCardData={this.loadCardData}
                  path={props.location.pathname}
                />
              )}
            />
<Route
              exact
              path="/:username/want"
              render={(props) => (
                <NewTable
                  data={this.state.data}
                  wantedCards={this.state.wantedCards}
                  loadCardData={this.loadCardData}
                  p1={props.location.pathname.split("/")[1]}
                  p2={props.location.pathname.split("/")[2]}
                  p3={props.location.pathname.split("/")[3]}
                  p4={props.location.pathname.split("/")[4]}
                  status="Want"
                  path={props.location.pathname}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/:username/want/team/:id"
              render={(props) => (
                <CardColumns
                  p1={props.location.pathname.split("/")[1]}
                  p2={props.location.pathname.split("/")[2]}
                  p3={props.location.pathname.split("/")[3]}
                  p4={props.location.pathname.split("/")[4]}
                  status="Want"
                  wantedCards={this.state.wantedCards}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  loadCardData={this.loadCardData}
                  path={props.location.pathname}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              render={function () {
                return <p>Not found</p>;
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in my `NewTable` and `CardColumns` components I call the `loadCardData` function in `componentDidMount()` passing in components' props.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadCardData(this.props);
  }
```

When I first go to the `path="/:username/own"` route the API request is made:
[image]

and `app.js` state is updated:
[image]

and the `NewTable` component props are set:
[image]

However when I then go to the `path="/:username/own/team/:id"` route the api is called again
[image]

and `console.log` reports `OWN TRUE` which tells me that

```
if (path[2] == "own" && props.ownedCards.length < 1) {
      console.log("OWN TRUE");
....
.... including axios call
}
```

is being met (i.e. `props.ownedCards` is empty).  However if I look at the component I can see props are set:
[image]

However if I then navigate back to the `path="/:username/own"` route no API call is made and the app makes use of the data in `props`.

Can anyone advise what the correct way is to makes sure that the components use the data in `props` rather than keep going back to the API?

Comment: You are calling loadCardData in your components again, why don't you just pass the result as props?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If I don't call `loadCardData` in `componentDidMount()` then the call doesn't happen.  Sorry I'm quite new to React so probably being dim

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you make the API call in your child components, it will always run when they are rendered. If you make it in your parent component, it will run when it (the parent) is rendered and you can pass the result as props to its children

Comment: Thanks.  What I want is for the API call to only be made if `wantedCards` (for `/want` routes) or `ownedCards` (for `/own` routes) is empty.  I don't want to have to keep going back to the API each time the component is rendered.  The neessary data lives in state on `app.js` or in the `props` on both components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem here was that in my table component I was using an  to link to other pages and this forced components to remount.

Changing this to <Link to= meant that state was not lost (which was passed down to child components via context api) and I could stop making unneccesary calls!